# How to reprogram stm32F769 DISCO board with the original DEMO code that it shipped with?

Tags: stm32, stm32f7

I'm playing around with the board in the question and I'm struggling with it even though I'm fairly familiar with the F767 Nucleo. What I want:

to reprogram the demo that came on to the board for now, as I haven't managed to get the display on the board working at all since before then. I've downloaded the stm32f769 disco demo that includes the appropriate .HEX

What I've done:

I've upgraded st-link using the upgrade utility. Within STM32 Cube programmer, I've selected the appropriate External Loader for my disco board. My board is connected via st-link and is recognised by cube programmer.

On the erasing and Programming tab I've selected the correct .HEX file and the device begins to program. The file is about 120MB and so takes a good while to program.
[image]

Once the programming has complete, cube programmer tells me that it was successful. However the screen is just displays the blue ST logo on a white background and nothing else. Nothing changes when tapping the screen or pressing the reset button (apart from a reset of course).

Any help would be appreciated, something simple as programming the board shouldn't be this difficult so I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm curious, how do you flash a 120MB file into a device that has only 2MB of flash?

Comment: There is 128MB QSPI flash on the disco board. Hence the need to use the external loader options to make use of the external flash

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the `readme.txt`?

Did you `click on "External Loader" from the bar menu then check "MX25L512G_STM32F769I-DISCO" box`?

because you need to flash the QSPI together with the internal 2MB memory.

Taken from the readme.txt in the [downloadable zip](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-discovery-kits/32f769idiscovery.html#).

> @par How to use it ?
>
> The QSPI external flash loader is not integrated with supported toolchains, its only supported with STM32
> ST-Link Utility V3.9 or later
> To load the demonstration, use STM32 ST-Link Utility to program both internal Flash and external QSPI memory.
> To edit and debug the demonstration you need first to program the external QSPI memory using STLink utility
> and then use your preferred toolchain to update and debug the internal flash content.
>
> In order to program the demonstration you must do the following:
>
> 1- Open STM32 ST-Link Utility, click on "External Loader" from the bar menu then check
> "MX25L512G_STM32F769I-DISCO" box
>
> 2- Connect the 32F769IDISCOVERY board to PC with USB cable through CN16
>
> 3- Use "STM32769I-DISCO_DEMO_VX.Y.Z_FULL.hex" file provided under Binary with STM32 ST-Link Utility
> to program both internal Flash and external QSPI memory. this demo to take benefit from Touch-GFX
> and EmbeddedWizard third parties demonstrations modules replacing Gardening control and Home alarm modules.
>
> 4- copy the audio and video files provided under "Media/" in the USB key
>
> 5- Plug a USB micro A-Male to A-Female cable on CN15 connector
>
> 6- Plug a headphone into CN7 Connector.
> -> The internal Flash and the external QSPI are now programmed and the demonstration is shown on the board.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I have done steps 1-3 already as noted in my question (I've underlined the appropriate external loader in the image etc.) The readme.txt comes from I assume the original demo not the  V1.2 demo that the board shipped with. Step 4 and 4 describe loading the media onto a USB stick and plugging in to CN15 micro USB. This is not necessary for the V1.2 demo as everything is stored on the QSPI